# Dual Boot Install Question

Tags: linux, software-installation, partition, home

I have Windows 7 and am going to reformat/reinstall, but want to try a dual boot configuration with Linux mint.  If I install Windows creating 3 partitions: one for Windows, one for Linux, and one for all of my data (to be accessed by Windows and Linux), is there still any need for me to create an additional "home" partition during the Linux install?  I am planning on creating a small swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have a separate home partition at all. The only problem with this configuration, is that if you ever need to reinstall from scratch, then you will need to backup your /home, as the root partition is usually formated again on new install. If you have your /home separated, you can safely reinstall keeping your data.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response.  Is there any data I need to worry about losing from the /home directory, in the scenario you noted, if I'm saving everything (documents, music, movies, etc.) to the shared data partition?

Comment: If you are saving your important information in your shared partition, the only data you may lose is the desktop configuration, and user defined settings that applications may set, as them are stored by default at /home.